# Use Dokku Environment variables in DockerFile

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile, dokku

I'm tring to use Dokku Environment variables in DockerFile but with no success.

Dokku Env is set with:

```
dokku config:set www NR_APP=AppName
```

In DockerFile, i would like to put this NR_APP to a file with:

```
RUN sh -c 'echo "newrelic.appname=\"$NR_APP\"" >> /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/newrelic.ini'
```

But it doesn't work, the result in file is:

```
newrelic.appname=
```

If i try to echo only ENV during build with:

```
RUN echo "$NR_APP"
```

It returns blank.

If i try to set NR_APP *inside* DockerFile with:

```
ENV NR_APP AppName
```

It works, but i don't want to define it inside DockerFile because it's a value that changes based on develop/production deployment and i've to do it also with license_key.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Dokku, but you will only be able to use those variables at run-time in a launched container.

Docker intentionally doesn't allow you to pass in variables to docker build, so that builds are reproducible across environments.

I suspect you can just write a script that configures the application at run-time using the given variables and then launches it. Just reference this script from the ENTRYPOINT or CMD instruction in the Dockerfile.

Comment: As wrote here: http://progrium.viewdocs.io/dokku/configuration-management:  "The variables are available both at at run time and during the application build/compilation step" 
But It appears to not work. I'll try with a script at bottom. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how Dokku works, but the only way to get a variable into the Dockerfile would be to build the Dockerfile from a template.